# Running Vespa outside Docker

Tags: vespa

I'd like to run an instance of Vespa outside of a container (e.g. Docker). The Docker path is definitely quite convenient and works great. But I would like to go thru the process by hand of setting up an instance on macOS and seeing more of the 'nuts and bolts' of Vespa.

It appears there are nice docs which outline a path to building RPM's for Centos, etc. Would walking thru that process and adapting to macOS be my best bet?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, running Vespa on MacOS directly is not yet supported. I'd suggest instead running a CentOS VM or cloud instance and experimenting there.